# GDI+ generic error on production server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, gdi+, system.drawing

I'm struggling on a massively answered problem but none of the given solutions is working for me.
I have a ASP.NET WebForms Application where I want to store pictures and be able to retrieve it, change rotation, remove, etc...
The thing is that everything works fine on my devlopment environment (with visual studio or even with IIS 8.5 on my local machine) but when I try to deploy it on my production server (IIS 10.0), I can't even upload a picture, I can only read pictures.
If I try to save, rotate or remove an image, I get a GDI+ generic error.
It makes me think it is a config or permission issue because the application is the same as on my machine and it works fine.

What I have tried :

- <%= Environment.UserName %> returns ".NET v4.5", I've granted this
  user with full permissions on the directory, even a full access given
  to "Everybody" user doesn't fix the issue.
- I have tried to dispose pictures after saving them but I dont'think
  it is caused by that because when i upload I'm not overwriting any
  file.
- "GC.Collect()" It does nothing, I didn't really understood why it
  would make a difference.
- I looked into IIS's MIME Types and "image/jpeg" is there.

The thing that disturbs me is that I have a directory for file upload (not pictures) in the same Application and it works so I guess the permissions are OK, I have the same permissions for both directories.

Here is my code for picture upload :

```
public static Int64 InsertPhoto(Photo maPhoto)
    {
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // ETAPE 1 : Récupération du numéro de photo
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        try
        {
            int? numero = PecV2.DAL.Photo.GetNumeroPhotoMaxByIDIntervention(maPhoto.IDIntervention);
        if (numero.HasValue)
        {
            maPhoto.Numero = numero.Value + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            maPhoto.Numero = 0;
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // ETAPE 2 : Génération des miniatures
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Intervention monIntervention = Intervention.GetIntervention(maPhoto.IDIntervention);
        maPhoto.IDImmeuble = monIntervention.IDImmeuble;
        maPhoto.FileName = maPhoto.IDImmeuble.ToString() + "_" + maPhoto.IDIntervention.ToString() + "_" + maPhoto.Numero.ToString() + ".jpg";

        maPhoto.EnregistrerMiniature(maPhoto.PhotoFull, global::PecV2.BL.Properties.Settings.Default.LargeurPhotoMedium, global::PecV2.BL.Properties.Settings.Default.RepertoirePhotosMedium, maPhoto.FileName);
        maPhoto.EnregistrerMiniature(maPhoto.PhotoFull, global::PecV2.BL.Properties.Settings.Default.LargeurPhotoSmall, global::PecV2.BL.Properties.Settings.Default.RepertoirePhotosSmall, maPhoto.FileName);
        // Encoder...                
        EncoderParameters encParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, (long)100);


        // Codec...
        ImageCodecInfo codecJpeg = null;
        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
            if (codec.MimeType == "image/jpeg")
                codecJpeg = codec;
            //GC.Collect();
            maPhoto.PhotoFull.Save(Path.Combine(global::PecV2.BL.Properties.Settings.Default.RepertoirePhotosFull, maPhoto.FileName), codecJpeg, encParams);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // ETAPE 3 : Enregistrement en base
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        return PecV2.DAL.Photo.InsertPhoto(maPhoto.IDImmeuble,
                                            maPhoto.IDIntervention,
                                            maPhoto.Remarques,
                                            maPhoto.Date,
                                            maPhoto.Numero,
                                            maPhoto.FileName);
    }

 private void EnregistrerMiniature(Bitmap PhotoSource, int DimMax, string RepertoireDestination, string NomFichier)
    {
        double RatioMedium;

        // détermination de l'orientation de la photo originale
        if (PhotoSource.Width >= PhotoSource.Height)
        {
            // photo horizontale
            RatioMedium = PhotoSource.Width / DimMax;
            //
        }
        else
        {
            // photo verticale
            RatioMedium = PhotoSource.Height / DimMax;
        }

        if (RatioMedium < 1)
            RatioMedium = 1;

        // Generation de la photo medium
        Int32 dW;
        Int32 dH;

        // Calcul de la résolution de la vignette par rapport à la largeur
        dW = (Int32)Math.Round(PhotoSource.Width / RatioMedium);
        dH = (Int32)Math.Round(PhotoSource.Height / RatioMedium);


        Bitmap bVignetteMedium = new Bitmap(dW, dH, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)bVignetteMedium))
        {
            // Temp pour supprimer bordure (G+H) noire
            SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
            g.FillRectangle(br, 0, 0, dW, dH);

            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
            g.DrawImage(PhotoSource, 0, 0, dW, dH);
        }
        // Encoder...                
        EncoderParameters encParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, (long)100);

        // Codec...
        ImageCodecInfo codecJpeg = null;
        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
            if (codec.MimeType == "image/jpeg")
                codecJpeg = codec;
        //Enregistrement de la vignette
        try
        {
            bVignetteMedium.Save(Path.Combine(RepertoireDestination, NomFichier), codecJpeg, encParams);
            bVignetteMedium.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Here is the full eror stack (btnEnregistrer_Click calls InsertPhoto):

```
[ExternalException (0x80004005): Une erreur générique s'est produite dans GDI+.]
 PecV2.WebApp.Intervention.Onglets.o07_Photos.btnEnregistrer_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +509
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +11802193
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +150
 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1735
```

------------------------------------------------UPDATE-----------------------------------------------

I have found out where the issue came from, It was a web.config problem, I was trying to open 'photos" directory instead of 'photo' directory... Don't laugh at me please!! I wonder how I have missed that X'D

thank you very much, Nicolas.

Comment: What line is actually throwing the error please?  At a guess I'd say this is rights, but too early to be sure.

Comment: [System.Drawing Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing(v=vs.110).aspx): "Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems...". That warning (or similar) has always existed, since .NET 1.1 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out where the issue came from, It was a web.config problem, I was trying to open 'photos" directory instead of 'photo' directory... Don't laugh at me please!! I wonder how I have missed that X'D